# Request timeout error when merge pdf files using pdfmerger

Tags: pdf

I am using this code and its working perfectly but when pdf is more then 50 its showing request timeout error

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

use PDFMerger\PDFMerger;
require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/cms/PDFMerger.php';
$pdf = new PDFMerger;
foreach($pdft as $pdf_file) {
    //echo $pdf_file;
    $pdf->addPDF($pdf_file)
        ->merge('file', $name.'.pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `merge()` call outside of the loop!

Currently you re-merge all files in each iteration. So instead of merging 50 documents a single time your process merges 1 file in the first iteration, 2 files in the second, 3 in the third,... 50 in the last one.

Simply reduce this to a single `merge()` call and you will save much process time:

```
use PDFMerger\PDFMerger;
require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/cms/PDFMerger.php';
$pdf = new PDFMerger;
foreach($pdft as $pdf_file) {
    $pdf->addPDF($pdf_file);
}

$pdf->merge('file', $name.'.pdf');
```

Comment: foreach($pdft as $pdf_file) {
    //echo $pdf_file;
    $pdf->addPDF($pdf_file)      
} ->merge('file', $name.'.pdf');    its not working when i add outside the loop

Comment: What you call "not working" is a fatal/syntax error. For sure you need to call the method on the object instance: `$pdf->merge('file', $name.'.pdf');`

Comment: Please provide me hint how to call the method on the object instance:$pdf->merge('file', $name.'.pdf'); for this..